# Legends for hue in seaborn count plot | Change position

Tags: matplotlib, plot, seaborn

In countplot legend for hue are placed at improper positition:

```
sns.countplot(x='cat114', hue='loss', data=data_tr)
```

[image: Countplot]

How do I change legend position?
I tried plt.legend(loc='upper right') but it is not helping me.

Comment: Did you put `plt.legend(loc='upper right')` before or after the `countplot`?

Comment: I put it after. I got my answer btw,  g=sns.countplot(x=feature, hue='loss', data=data_tr,
                  order=cat_order(feature))
    g.figure.get_axes()[0].legend(loc='upper right')

Comment: Sounds good. Feel free to post that as an official answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
g=sns.countplot(x=feature, hue='loss', data=data_tr) 
g.figure.get_axes()[0].legend(title='loss',loc='upper right')
```

Comment: `g.figure.get_axes()[0]` is just returning `g` here.